# Is it possible to send a local message on the EventBus?

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

The only thing I've found in the API is [`localConsumer`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#localConsumer-java.lang.String-) so my idea was to register the consumer twice - once using `consumer` and once using `localConsumer` with the address prefixed by *local:*.

Here's an example:

```
public class VertxLocal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);
        HazelcastClusterManager cm = new HazelcastClusterManager(config);

        // This is io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx
        Vertx.clusteredVertxObservable(new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(cm))
            .subscribe(vertx -> {
                EventBus bus = vertx.eventBus();

                // Register the "public" consumer
                bus.consumer("test")
                    .toObservable()
                    .subscribe(message -> {
                        message.reply(id.toString());
                    });
                // Register the local consumer
                bus.localConsumer("local:test")
                    .toObservable()
                    .subscribe(message -> {
                        message.reply(id.toString());
                    });

                // Periodically retrieve replies from the local consumer
                vertx.setPeriodic(1, i -> {
                    bus.sendObservable("local:test", id.toString())
                        .subscribe(reply -> {
                            UUID fromId = UUID.fromString((String)reply.body());
                            if(fromId.equals(id)) {
                                System.out.println("Received message from local handler");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Received message from remote handler");
                            }
                        });
                });
            });
    }
}
```

This works, but it's rather ugly to register each consumer twice - I'd rather only choose if should be a local message or not when sending the message.

Is there any way of doing this without registering a local consumer - something like `localSend` (though I can't see anything like that in the API)?

Comment: @mhstnsc: To clarify why I reverted your edit: I'm not asking to *favour* a local consumer - I wanted to send a *completely* local message - i.e. if there is no local consumer it shouldn't be handled at all.

Comment: then i don't really get it. The code you pasted registers a local consumer and a global consumer. How does this enhance to what you really want to ask? Why is there a global consumer in the code. You don't even want to send a message to it.

Comment: if you only want a local consumer , why would you register it globally

Comment: Other services should still send messages to the global consumer, but messages sent from this service shouldn't show up at other services.

Comment: Your approach is right. The other way is to add interceptor on eventbus that changes address from `test` to `local:test` if a message contains header `isLocal`, for example.